# Eclipse update ==> "No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor"

Tags: eclipse, pydev

An eclipse update offered, taken. Restart accepted.

Now no editor in the IDE?

Revert had a "problem".

Found only really old references to the same message. Saying things like check PyDev installed.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: I removed eclipse. REinstalled from an old file. Reinstalled pydev. NO change.

Comment: No change.<NEWLINE!> 5 more to go"????

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue just now on eclipse 4.8 (photon). It turns out that I upgraded pydev from 8.2 to 9.1 which requires java 11 to run.

Installing java 11 as well as setting as default (using alternatives -- config java) and uninstalling pydev (Help -> about Eclipse -> Installation details -> looking for PyDev and uninstalling) and reinstalling it (Help -> Install new software) solved my problem.